# Is it good etiquette to automate the earning of badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

I noticed that the process of earning some badges could be automated (and others with an army of bots), so I am thinking of writing an app called Badger to automate this. Is this good etiquette?

Comment: Not a massive fan

Comment: Also; don't you have real work to do?

Comment: @RichardTingle Which is exactly why he's automating it...

Comment: What would be the point? This is the equivalent of cheating at solitaire. The badges are meaningless unless you actually earn them, especially when you've publicly announced that you intend to cheat to get them. You don't get any credit for having them when you get them without the effort.

Comment: Also, if your "automation" abuses any kind of site feature that affects other users (like automatic voting or reviewing), that's certainly grounds for a lengthy suspension.

Comment: Automating badges based on view count could be considered DoS, you wouldn't like risking landing in Guantanamo? ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nope, that is pretty much the worst type of etiquette.

"Etiquette is a code of behavior that delineates expectations for social behavior according to contemporary conventional norms within a group." <sup>[wiki - Etiquette](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etiquette)</sup>

I do not think the conventional wisdom for stack exchange badges is to automate achieving them. Botting is frowned upon, there is even a script which searches for botters.

Automating the achievement of badges would amount to exploitation.

Comment: Then Jon Skeet must be banned!

Comment: @ColeJohnson - Oh! Well I never..

Comment: Banning Jon Skeet is heresy.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Please... slow down on the Skeet worship and memes. This is not the MSO of 2009.

Comment: @yoda but that was 6-8 weeks ago!

Comment: Jon Who? Meh...

Comment: @James run while you still can